# HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR expected 'STRING' but 'STRING' is found

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I've been unable to get any query to work against my AWS Glue Partitioned table. The error I'm getting is

> HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Error:
>   type expected at the position 0 of 'STRING' but 'STRING' is found.
>   (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)

I've found one other thread that brings up the fact that the database name and table cannot have characters other than alphanumeric and underscores. So, I made sure the database name, table name and all column names adhere to this restriction. The only object that does not adhere to this restriction is my s3 bucket name which would be very difficult to change.

Here are the table definitions and parquet-tools dumps of the data.

### AWS Glue Table Definition

```
{
    "Table": {
        "UpdateTime": 1545845064.0, 
        "PartitionKeys": [
            {
                "Comment": "call_time year", 
                "Type": "INT", 
                "Name": "date_year"
            }, 
            {
                "Comment": "call_time month", 
                "Type": "INT", 
                "Name": "date_month"
            }, 
            {
                "Comment": "call_time day", 
                "Type": "INT", 
                "Name": "date_day"
            }
        ], 
        "StorageDescriptor": {
            "OutputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat", 
            "SortColumns": [], 
            "InputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat", 
            "SerdeInfo": {
                "SerializationLibrary": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe", 
                "Name": "ser_de_info_system_admin_created", 
                "Parameters": {
                    "serialization.format": "1"
                }
            }, 
            "BucketColumns": [], 
            "Parameters": {}, 
            "Location": "s3://ph-data-lake-cududfs2z3xveg5t/curated/system/admin_created/", 
            "NumberOfBuckets": 0, 
            "StoredAsSubDirectories": false, 
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Comment": "Unique user ID", 
                    "Type": "STRING", 
                    "Name": "user_id"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "Unique group ID", 
                    "Type": "STRING", 
                    "Name": "group_id"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "Date and time the message was published", 
                    "Type": "TIMESTAMP", 
                    "Name": "call_time"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "call_time year", 
                    "Type": "INT", 
                    "Name": "date_year"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "call_time month", 
                    "Type": "INT", 
                    "Name": "date_month"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "call_time day", 
                    "Type": "INT", 
                    "Name": "date_day"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "Given name for user", 
                    "Type": "STRING", 
                    "Name": "given_name"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "IANA time zone for user", 
                    "Type": "STRING", 
                    "Name": "time_zone"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "Name that links to geneaology", 
                    "Type": "STRING", 
                    "Name": "family_name"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "Email address for user", 
                    "Type": "STRING", 
                    "Name": "email"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "RFC BCP 47 code set in this user's profile language and region", 
                    "Type": "STRING", 
                    "Name": "language"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "Phone number including ITU-T ITU-T E.164 country codes", 
                    "Type": "STRING", 
                    "Name": "phone"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "Date user was created", 
                    "Type": "TIMESTAMP", 
                    "Name": "date_created"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "User role", 
                    "Type": "STRING", 
                    "Name": "role"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "Provider dashboard preferences", 
                    "Type": "STRUCT<portal_welcome_done:BOOLEAN,weekend_digests:BOOLEAN,patients_hidden:BOOLEAN,last_announcement:STRING>", 
                    "Name": "preferences"
                }, 
                {
                    "Comment": "Provider notification settings", 
                    "Type": "STRUCT<digest_email:BOOLEAN>", 
                    "Name": "notifications"
                }
            ], 
            "Compressed": true
        }, 
        "Parameters": {
            "classification": "parquet", 
            "parquet.compress": "SNAPPY"
        }, 
        "Description": "System wide admin_created messages", 
        "Name": "system_admin_created", 
        "TableType": "EXTERNAL_TABLE", 
        "Retention": 0
    }
}
```

### AWS Athena schema

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `system_admin_created`(
  `user_id` STRING COMMENT 'Unique user ID', 
  `group_id` STRING COMMENT 'Unique group ID', 
  `call_time` TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Date and time the message was published', 
  `date_year` INT COMMENT 'call_time year', 
  `date_month` INT COMMENT 'call_time month', 
  `date_day` INT COMMENT 'call_time day', 
  `given_name` STRING COMMENT 'Given name for user', 
  `time_zone` STRING COMMENT 'IANA time zone for user', 
  `family_name` STRING COMMENT 'Name that links to geneaology', 
  `email` STRING COMMENT 'Email address for user', 
  `language` STRING COMMENT 'RFC BCP 47 code set in this user\'s profile language and region', 
  `phone` STRING COMMENT 'Phone number including ITU-T ITU-T E.164 country codes', 
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Date user was created', 
  `role` STRING COMMENT 'User role', 
  `preferences` STRUCT<portal_welcome_done:BOOLEAN,weekend_digests:BOOLEAN,patients_hidden:BOOLEAN,last_announcement:STRING> COMMENT 'Provider dashboard preferences', 
  `notifications` STRUCT<digest_email:BOOLEAN> COMMENT 'Provider notification settings')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `date_year` INT COMMENT 'call_time year', 
  `date_month` INT COMMENT 'call_time month', 
  `date_day` INT COMMENT 'call_time day')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://ph-data-lake-cududfs2z3xveg5t/curated/system/admin_created/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'parquet.compress'='SNAPPY')
```

### parquet-tools cat

```
role = admin
date_created = 2018-01-11T14:40:23.142Z
preferences:
.patients_hidden = false
.weekend_digests = true
.portal_welcome_done = true
email = foo.barr+123@example.com
notifications:
.digest_email = true
group_id = 5a5399df23a804001aa25227
given_name = foo
call_time = 2018-01-11T14:40:23.000Z
time_zone = US/Pacific
family_name = bar
language = en-US
user_id = 5a5777572060a700170240c3
```

### parquet-tools schema

```
message spark_schema {
  optional binary role (UTF8);
  optional binary date_created (UTF8);
  optional group preferences {
    optional boolean patients_hidden;
    optional boolean weekend_digests;
    optional boolean portal_welcome_done;
    optional binary last_announcement (UTF8);
  }
  optional binary email (UTF8);
  optional group notifications {
    optional boolean digest_email;
  }
  optional binary group_id (UTF8);
  optional binary given_name (UTF8);
  optional binary call_time (UTF8);
  optional binary time_zone (UTF8);
  optional binary family_name (UTF8);
  optional binary language (UTF8);
  optional binary user_id (UTF8);
  optional binary phone (UTF8);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend getting full stacktrace of your exception. You probably can't get this from Athena, but Presto supports Glue natively

Comment: The issue seems to be with data type mismatch.Are you still facing the issue after correcting the table DDL matching the schema generated by parquet-tools schema ? If it's not working attach the sample parquet using https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-post

Comment: I was declaring the partition keys as fields in the table. I also ran into the Parquet vs Hive difference in TIMESTAMP and switched those to ISO8601 strings. From there, I pretty much gave up because Athena throws a schema error if all parquet files in the s3 buckets do not have the same schema as Athena. However, with optional fields and sparse columns this is guaranteed to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was declaring the partition keys as fields in the table. I also ran into the Parquet vs Hive difference in TIMESTAMP and switched those to ISO8601 strings. From there, I pretty much gave up because Athena throws a schema error if all parquet files in the s3 buckets do not have the same schema as Athena. However, with optional fields and sparse columns this is guaranteed to happen

Answer (score 8):

I ran into a similar PrestoException and the cause was using uppercase letters for the column type.  Once I changed 'VARCHAR(10)' to 'varchar(10)' then it worked.

Comment: This is so frustrating. The error message even has these in uppercase!!!!! Thanks

Comment: One year later and this still exists. Athena is just not a fully baked product yet.

Comment: While the answer shows nice research, that is just not a good way for Athena to behave.  In SSMS, case insensitivity is usually what happens ...

Comment: I have reported this issue to amazon using the feedback form. Everyone encountering this bug should do the same and one day it will be fixed. Use this link: https://docs-feedback.aws.amazon.com/feedback.jsp?hidden_service_name=Athena&topic_url=http://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this error and of course, the error message ended up telling me nothing about the actual problem. I had the exact same error as the original poster.

I am creating my glue tables via the python boto3 API and feeding it the column names, types, partition columns, and some other things. The problem:

here was my code that I was using to create the table:

```
import boto3

glu_clt = boto3.client("glue", region_name="us-east-1")

glue_clt.create_table(
    DatabaseName=database,
    TableInput={
        "Name": table,
        "StorageDescriptor": {
            "Columns": table_cols,
            "Location": table_location,
            "InputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat",
            "OutputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat",
            "SerdeInfo": {
                "SerializationLibrary": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe",
            }
        },
        "PartitionKeys": partition_cols,
        "TableType": "EXTERNAL_TABLE"
    }
)
```

So I ended defining all the column names and types for the input `Columns` to the API. Then I was also giving it the column name and type for the input `PartitionKeys` in the API. When I browsed to the AWS console, I realized because I defined the partition column both in the `Columns` and `PartitionKeys`, it was defined twice in the table.

Interestingly enough, if you try to do this via the console, it will throw a more descriptive error letting you know that the column already exists (if you try adding a partition column that already exists in the table).

TO SOLVE:
I removed the partition columns and their types from the input `Columns` and instead just fed them through the `PartitionKeys` input so they wouldn't be put on the table twice. Soooooo frustrating that this was ultimately causing the same error message as the OP's when querying through Athena.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be related to how you created your database (whether through CloudFormation or UI or CLI) or if you have any forbidden characters like '-'. We have hyphens in our database and table names and it renders much functionality useless.

Answer (score 0):

please check view in the glue maybe wrong inalization of data type is their in the glue and we need to fix it after the deployment.
in my case integrer was deployed but the glue column would take float only